# Can driver earnings be accessed through Uber API?

Tags: uber-api

Does the public [Uber API](https://developer.uber.com/v1/endpoints/) have the functionality to see how much a driver has made. I can see that companies like [SherpaShare](https://www.sherpashare.com/driver/dashboard/) are able to pull these values, but I can't find any documentation on how to do this through the API.

Answer (score 0):

We currently do not have API endpoints that provide information about driver activity. This is something we are considering, but at this time we do not have any public plans for a release.

Comment: Hi @Alec, are you working with Uber API? I dohave some API related questions for you if you don't mind.

Comment: Yes! Feel free to post API questions with the uber-api tag and we'll do our best to answer. Also, thanks for all your help answering various Uber API questions on Stack Overflow!